# Want to display text from a UITableViewCell to a Local Notification alertBody

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, variables, uilocalnotification

When the cell grays out, I want to create a Local Notification. In the alertBody want to have the text read what is in the cell and send that to the local notification. Only the Alert! displays without the .alertBody. Have tried several different approaches but no success to get the local alert to display what is in the grayed out cell.

TableViewController.h

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *transmitterNameLabel;

TableViewController.m

@synthesize transmitterNameLabel;

...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyReusableCell";
SightingsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell != nil) {
    Transmitter *transmitter = [self.transmitters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Update the transmitter text
    cell.transmitterNameLabel.text = transmitter.name;

    // Update the transmitter avatar (icon image)
    NSInteger avatarID = [UserSettingsRepository getAvatarIDForTransmitterID:transmitter.identifier];
    NSString *imageFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"avatar_%02ld.png", (long)avatarID];
    cell.transmitterIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageFilename];

    if ([self isTransmitterAgedOut:transmitter]) {
        [self grayOutSightingsCell:cell];
        //Add Local Notification
        NSDate *AlertTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:3];
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
                              UILocalNotification *notifyAlert = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                              if (notifyAlert) {
                                  notifyAlert.fireDate = AlertTime;
                                  notifyAlert.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                                  notifyAlert.repeatInterval = 0;
                                  notifyAlert.soundName = @"soundeffect.mp3";
                                  notifyAlert.alertBody = transmitterNameLabel.text;
                                  notifyAlert.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
                                  [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlert];
                                   }
    } else {
        [self updateSightingsCell:cell withTransmitter:transmitter];
    }
}
return cell;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update the label, you call `cell.transmitterNameLabel.text = transmitter.name;` which updates the `transmitterNameLabel` property in the `SightingsTableViewCell` class object `cell`, but when setting `alertBody`, you call `notifyAlert.alertBody = transmitterNameLabel.text;` which is not a property of the `cell` object and thus may be empty/different.

Perhaps you should try `notifyAlert.alertBody = cell.transmitterNameLabel.text;`?

Comment: Thanks this is correct! I now get the object name showing up in the notification. Thanks you helped me a lot.